# File was processed with these loaders: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

File was processed with these loaders:../node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js

You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

...rest

} = props;

const id useMemo (() => anId ?? generateId(), [anid]);

const elementWrapperRef = useRef(null);

const nonEventChangeRefuseRef(true);

The react app is working perfectly on my laptop. But when I have tried my react app on other system by cloning it using git it gives this error. I have updated the babel-loader but it's still showing this error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.